# How to write 'number of ...' in a unit?

Tags: atmosphere

**Q:** Which unit is attached to '*number of particles per volume*' (e.g. of the atmosphere)? The questions focuses on the '**number of**' and not on the 'volume'.

The units [#/m<sup>3</sup>], [particles/m<sup>3</sup>] and [1/m<sup>3</sup>] are used in publications. Neither [#/m<sup>3</sup>] nor [particles/m<sup>3</sup>] are SI compliant. However, [1/m<sup>3</sup>] would be SI compliant but it looks ... incomplete.

*edit 1:*
The particles are of different size and composition. Converting the number of particles into another unit is not reasonable for my application.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about academia.

Comment: Where would you suggest to ask this question instead?

Comment: [Mole](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mole_%28unit%29)? My chemistry/physics is a bit rusty...

Comment: Thank you @JanDoggen for the suggestion. The particles are of different size and composition. Giving them in mole is not reasonable in this situation.

Comment: In my experience $[m^{-3}]$ or $[cm^{-3}]$ is perfectly reasonable and well understood in the literature.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with particles per unit volume. However, if the number of particles is very large (e.g., $10^{26}$ particles per unit volume), it would be better to use number of moles rather than number of particles.

Comment: @DavidHammen, yes and the fact that "The particles are of different size and composition." does not get in the way. A mole is in fact a unitless quantity, $6.022 \times 10^{23}$, and often applied to mixed gases, liquids and amorphous solids where the definition of "particles" is clear.

Comment: @DavidHammen and Aabaakawad: Thank you for the replys!

Comment: @AtmosphericPrisonEscape if you put that as an answer, I'd upvote it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In my experience $[m^{-3}]$ or $[cm^{-3}]$ as number density is very well understood throughout the communities of both earth, solar-system as well as exoplanetary scientists.

Take for example the recently published [The atmosphere of Pluto as observed by New Horizons](http://science.sciencemag.org/content/351/6279/aad8866.full) which in fig. 3 shows the derived atmospheric composition of Pluto from occultation measurments in $[cm^{-3}]$ with some model curves:

[image] (Property of G. R. Gladstone et. al 2016 and the New Horizons Science team)

The density in this unit is just a very natural and convenient outcome of the used occultation-inversion techniques. Thus of course the units are sometimes simply the result of the context in which a work is done, and as other commentators stated, a mole could be used.
However I'd argue that $[cm^{-3}]$ is sufficiently simple to be understood in any context and adding moles just makes things unnecessary confusing as it suggests numbers to have a unit, which they don't.
It just physically makes no sense.